# Making CMake print commands before executing

Tags: linux, cmake, gnu-make

I'm working on a large C++ project built with CMake on Linux.  CMake runs okay, producing a horde of Makefiles in the tree of modules and applications. Running GNU `make` leads to linker errors.  How can I get `make` to print out the exact commands before running them?

The -d option does not print the commands, but plenty of information that hasn't been helpful.

The -n option prints all the commands, but does not run them, so I can't tell were exactly the trouble is. Examining the stdout from make -n, I don't see any commands that are relevant. I suspect some commands change depending on the results of earlier commands, and the hierarchy of Makefiles makes it difficult to tell what's really going on.

I don't see any other options in make's *man* page that seem helpful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Cmake with GNU Make: How can I see the exact commands?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670121/using-cmake-with-gnu-make-how-can-i-see-the-exact-commands)

Answer (score 104, accepted):

I am fairly sure this will work:

```
make VERBOSE=1
```

You should also be able to add this to your CMakeLists.txt to permanently set that:

```
set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE on)
```

This is covered in the [CMake FAQ](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/FAQ).

Comment: Yup, that did it!   Next thing to debug: why wasn't I able to find that in the documentation?

Comment: Is there a way, I can customize the output? For example, if I want to insert custom echo between compiling and linking such as echo "this is the end of compiling and now we will start linking"...

Comment: I found the answer -> add_custom_command(TARGET yourtargetname POST_BUILD COMMAND echo "WE HAVE FINISHED COMPILING")

Answer (score 10):

For those using [`cmake --build`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.14/manual/cmake.1.html#build-a-project), which invokes `make` internally, use either:

```
  $ cmake --build <dir> -- VERBOSE=1
```

Note the `--` before `VERBOSE=1`!  That passes the argument to the underlying `make` process.

Or:

```
  $ VERBOSE=1 cmake --build <dir>
```

which also passes `VERBOSE=1` to `make`, this time via an environment variable.

Or, if using `cmake` **version 3.14** or higher:

```
  $ cmake --build <dir> --verbose
```

Note the order of the arguments!  The `--verbose` option must come after `--build` and its argument.

Answer (score 6):

For automake-generated Makefiles, try:

```
make V=1
```

Comment: Not on topic, the question is about cmake, not automake.

Answer (score 6):

An option, which applies to GNU make and works with any Makefile, whether generated by CMake or not, is to use the `--trace` option to make. This will print out the commands `make` is executing and still execute them.

This applies to all commands, not just those that `VERBOSE=1` or `V=1` triggers the printing of in CMake/automake generated makefiles.

And yet another alternative on Linux is to run make under [strace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace), as `strace -f -e trace=execve make <make options>`. The output from strace will include *every* process that is executed: by make, by a shell script that make ran, etc.

For instance, you might find that the CMake-generated makefile executes `/usr/bin/cmake -E __run_co_compile <lots of options ...>` and still wonder what the exact compiler invocation(s) are that this in turn will run. You can get that with the strace method.

Comment: The equivalent on Windows to `strace` would be [Process Monitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_Monitor).