# Building C++ Allegro 5 fails on Linux Mint QT

Tags: c++, linux, build, allegro5

I am installing and building Allegro 5 from Git (tried normal install and it failed the same way).
I don't know what to do next to make this compile.

```
[ 20%] Building C object addons/native_dialog/CMakeFiles/allegro_dialog.dir/gtk_xgtk.c.o
[ 20%] Linking C shared library ../../lib/liballegro_dialog.so
[ 20%] Built target allegro_dialog
Scanning dependencies of target allegro_main
[ 20%] Building C object addons/main/CMakeFiles/allegro_main.dir/generic_main.c.o
[ 20%] Linking C shared library ../../lib/liballegro_main.so
[ 20%] Built target allegro_main
Scanning dependencies of target copy_demo_data
[ 20%] Generating data/gfx/medium_asteroid.png
CMake Error: cmake version 3.5.1
Usage: /usr/bin/cmake -E <command> [arguments...]

demos/cosmic_protector/CMakeFiles/copy_demo_data.dir/build.make:97: recipe for target 'demos/cosmic_protector/data/gfx/medium_asteroid.png' failed
make[2]: *** [demos/cosmic_protector/data/gfx/medium_asteroid.png] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:844: recipe for target 'demos/cosmic_protector/CMakeFiles/copy_demo_data.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [demos/cosmic_protector/CMakeFiles/copy_demo_data.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:127: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

`
Done with; make VERBOSE 1:

```
make[2]: Entering directory '/media/oneterebyte/Documents/ALL DOUGLAS'/Eclipse C Projects/allegro5/build'
[ 20%] Generating data/gfx/medium_asteroid.png
cd "/media/oneterebyte/Documents/ALL DOUGLAS'/Eclipse C Projects/allegro5/build/demos/cosmic_protector" && /usr/bin/cmake -E copy /media/oneterebyte/Documents/ALL\ DOUGLAS'/Eclipse\ C\ Projects/allegro5/demos/cosmic_protector/data/gfx/medium_asteroid.png /media/oneterebyte/Documents/ALL\ DOUGLAS'/Eclipse\ C\ Projects/allegro5/build/demos/cosmic_protector/data/gfx/medium_asteroid.png
CMake Error: cmake version 3.5.1
Usage: /usr/bin/cmake -E <command> [arguments...]
Available commands: 


demos/cosmic_protector/CMakeFiles/copy_demo_data.dir/build.make:97: recipe for target 'demos/cosmic_protector/data/gfx/medium_asteroid.png' failed
make[2]: *** [demos/cosmic_protector/data/gfx/medium_asteroid.png] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/media/oneterebyte/Documents/ALL DOUGLAS'/Eclipse C Projects/allegro5/build'
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:844: recipe for target 'demos/cosmic_protector/CMakeFiles/copy_demo_data.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [demos/cosmic_protector/CMakeFiles/copy_demo_data.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/media/oneterebyte/Documents/ALL DOUGLAS'/Eclipse C Projects/allegro5/build'
Makefile:127: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: What commands did you run to build it? Can you try `make VERBOSE=1? (https://stackoverflow.com/a/4808324/1435461)

Comment: I am following this web page: https://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=Install_Allegro5_From_Git/Linux/Debian
This error showed up after typing make.

Comment: Unfortunaly I'm not sure. If you are just interested in installing allegro and not the demos, you can disable them with [`WANT_DEMO=0`](https://github.com/liballeg/allegro5/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L188)

Comment: WANT DEMO=0 is a command for make? It does not work; make: *** No rule to make target 'WANT'.  Stop.

Comment: it is a command to cmake, e.g. `cmake -DWANT_DEMO=off`. Note the `_`, it is `WANT_DEMO`, not `WANT DEMO`

Comment: Did you try directly via terminal with: sudo apt-get install liballegro5-dev  ?

Answer (score 0):

I went to long way around and removed Mint KDE (because they are not going to update it and it was really out of date) and installed Manjaro KDE Linux. This came with all the programming tools I need and it is VERY up to date!

Thanks everyone!