# Pcap functions undefined reference

Tags: c++, cmake, clion, pcap, undefined-reference

I'm trying to add pcap functions into my C++ project in Clion on linux.

My h file contains:

```
#include <pcap/pcap.h>
```

And the CMAKE file was updated as well.

Instead of using the next command:

```
if (NOT MSVC)
    target_link_libraries(${TARGET} pthread)
endif()
```

it is now:

```
if (NOT MSVC)
    target_link_libraries(${TARGET} pthread pcap)
endif()
```

still getting the next errors:

```
undefined reference to "pcap_open_dead"
undefined reference to "pcap_dump_open"
undefined reference to "pcap_dump_close"
undefined reference to "pcap_close"
```

Anyone knows how to solve it?

Thanks

Comment: Can you compile in [`VERBOSE`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4808303/7582247) mode and show the output you get?

Comment: And please tell us where the pcap library is actually located...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help!

After using the VERBOSE flag I was able to see the problem.

I added the pcap flag in another CMAKE file and now it works :)