C headers in C++ - PipeWire c example to c++
i wanted to use this c example code for the PipeWire API to generate a simple tone. For different reasons I want to use C++ for my project, so my plan was to refactor the code to work with C++.
So first of all I followed the getting stated page and installed the pipewire dev headers apt install libpipewire-0.3-dev.
Testing the C code
Then I created a project in c to test if the code is working as expected.
The CMakeLists file I use
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.29)
project(pipewire_ctest C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)

find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(PIPEWIRE REQUIRED libpipewire-0.3)

include_directories(${PIPEWIRE_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(pipewire_ctest main.c)

target_link_libraries(pipewire_ctest ${PIPEWIRE_LIBRARIES} m)

The main.c file
My main.c file contains the code which was also given with the link above
Compiler
gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 13.2.0-23ubuntu4) 13.2.0

With the CLion IDE I built and executed the code, which works without errors and results in a played sound.
Trying with c++
Now I tried to refactor the code to c++.
The CMakeLists file I use for C++
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.29)
project(pipewire_test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)

find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(PIPEWIRE REQUIRED libpipewire-0.3)

include_directories(${PIPEWIRE_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(pipewire_test main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(pipewire_test ${PIPEWIRE_LIBRARIES})

The main.cpp file
changes I made:

mark the headers as extern C
static_cast for void pointers to structs
removed designated initializer clauses
added a separated struct audio_info

#include <math.h>

extern "C"
{
    #include <spa/param/audio/format-utils.h>
    #include <pipewire/pipewire.h>
}

#define M_PI_M2 ( M_PI + M_PI )
#define DEFAULT_RATE            44100
#define DEFAULT_CHANNELS        2
#define DEFAULT_VOLUME          0.7

struct data {
    pw_main_loop *loop;
    pw_stream *stream;
    double accumulator;
};

/* [on_process] */
static void on_process(void *userdata)
{
    struct data *data =  static_cast<struct data*>(userdata);
    struct pw_buffer *b;
    struct spa_buffer *buf;
    int i, c, n_frames, stride;
    int16_t *dst, val;

    if ((b = pw_stream_dequeue_buffer(data->stream)) == NULL) {
        pw_log_warn("out of buffers: %m");
        return;
    }

    buf = b->buffer;
    if ((dst = static_cast<int16_t*>(buf->datas[0].data)) == NULL)
        return;

        stride = sizeof(int16_t) * DEFAULT_CHANNELS;
        n_frames = buf->datas[0].maxsize / stride;
        if (b->requested)
                n_frames = SPA_MIN(b->requested, n_frames);

        for (i = 0; i < n_frames; i++) {
                data->accumulator += M_PI_M2 * 440 / DEFAULT_RATE;
                if (data->accumulator >= M_PI_M2)
                        data->accumulator -= M_PI_M2;

                /* sin() gives a value between -1.0 and 1.0, we first apply
                 * the volume and then scale with 32767.0 to get a 16 bits value
                 * between [-32767 32767].
                 * Another common method to convert a double to
                 * 16 bits is to multiply by 32768.0 and then clamp to
                 * [-32768 32767] to get the full 16 bits range. */
                val = sin(data->accumulator) * DEFAULT_VOLUME * 32767.0;
                for (c = 0; c < DEFAULT_CHANNELS; c++)
                        *dst++ = val;
        }

        buf->datas[0].chunk->offset = 0;
        buf->datas[0].chunk->stride = stride;
        buf->datas[0].chunk->size = n_frames * stride;

        pw_stream_queue_buffer(data->stream, b);
}
/* [on_process] */

static const struct pw_stream_events stream_events = {
        PW_VERSION_STREAM_EVENTS,
        on_process,
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        struct data data = { 0, };
        const struct spa_pod *params[1];
        uint8_t buffer[1024];
        struct spa_pod_builder b = SPA_POD_BUILDER_INIT(buffer, sizeof(buffer));

        pw_init(&argc, &argv);

        data.loop = pw_main_loop_new(NULL);

        data.stream = pw_stream_new_simple(
                        pw_main_loop_get_loop(data.loop),
                        "audio-src",
                        pw_properties_new(
                                PW_KEY_MEDIA_TYPE, "Audio",
                                PW_KEY_MEDIA_CATEGORY, "Playback",
                                PW_KEY_MEDIA_ROLE, "Music",
                                NULL),
                        &stream_events,
                        &data);

        struct spa_audio_info_raw audio_info = SPA_AUDIO_INFO_RAW_INIT(
            SPA_AUDIO_FORMAT_S16,
            DEFAULT_CHANNELS,
            DEFAULT_RATE
        );

        params[0] = spa_format_audio_raw_build(&b, SPA_PARAM_EnumFormat, &audio_info);


        pw_stream_connect(data.stream,
                          PW_DIRECTION_OUTPUT,
                          PW_ID_ANY,
                          static_cast<pw_stream_flags>(PW_STREAM_FLAG_AUTOCONNECT |
                          PW_STREAM_FLAG_MAP_BUFFERS |
                          PW_STREAM_FLAG_RT_PROCESS),
                          params, 1);

        pw_main_loop_run(data.loop);

        pw_stream_destroy(data.stream);
        pw_main_loop_destroy(data.loop);

        return 0;
}

Also compiled and executed, there is no error, but no sound is played. However, using the qpwgraph software, I can see the audio-src node that is successfully created. What am I doing wrong?

Sidenote: Drop extern "C" {...} around the headers. They deal with that internally

I guess on_process is some sort of a callback, correct? Does your code ever reach it?

BTW why did you remove the designated initializers? It feels like on_process should be assigned to .process field of pw_stream_events, currently it's likely to be assigned to .destroy if the order in the docs is the same as in the code: https://docs.pipewire.org/structpw__stream__events.html#abbe98bb0d78e6411d08244495f349b0b

@alagner, possibly because they're using a C++ compiler that does not support designated initializers?  C has had them since C99, whereas C++ did not introduce them until C++20.  But you're right that without designators, one needs to pay careful attention to the order of the initializers.

@JohnBollinger gcc has supported designated initializers in C++ for a long time already, either in C++20 mode or as an extension. If the latter is a reasonable solution or not can be argued, but they generally work unless some compliance options are set. These are not in OP's CMakeLists.txt And even if they were, please notice C++ is set to version 23 anyway. Maybe designated initializers would require some tweaking (I know in C++ and C they behave a bit differently), but still it would be closer to the original working version.

@alagner Adding the output of make VERBOSE=1 so we could see the actual arguments passed to the compiler and linker would help.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4808303/making-cmake-print-commands-before-executing
