# CMake: how to show the compiler's stdout

Tags: gcc, cmake

This should be really simple, but I am having a hard time figuring it out. Usually, when building the project with **make**, only the stderr of the compiler is shown. How can I configure CMake to display the stdout of the compiler also?
I am using GCC, if this should matter.

Comment: Not sure, but `make VERBOSE=1` and `CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE` variable might be relevant.

Comment: Both of these actually do the same thing and it does include the compiler's standard output to the standard output of make. The thing I wanted to do was to run only the preprocessor by giving to gcc the "-E" option. I thought wrongly that it would output the result to the standard output. It turns out it puts it in the out file. That is way I was dazzled when I did not see it. If you make an answer out of your comment I would accept it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Cmake with GNU Make: How can I see the exact commands?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670121/using-cmake-with-gnu-make-how-can-i-see-the-exact-commands)

Comment: If you will be doing this a lot, consider something polished and well packaged, documented, and easy to use like "Better Enums", a single-header library for doing all this and more.  http://aantron.github.io/better-enums/

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can use `make VERBOSE=1` and the `CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE` variable to show commands being run by CMake.

CMake also automatically generates preprocess targets for sources, but there is no target to preprocess every source at once. To preprocess a single file, run `make source.i`, and it would appear in `CMakeFiles/<targetname>.dir/source.i`. Actual paths may differ, so if it doesn't work, you can check `Makefile` generated by CMake for the appropriate target.

Comment: I agree. `set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)` at the top of your `CMakeLists.txt`

Comment: A few examples (command lines and/or otherwise) would be in order.