# "undefined reference to `GOACC_parallel_keyed' " and related errors coming up while running make command

Tags: fortran, linker-errors, openacc

I am working on a project where I have to optimise the performance of a Computational Fluid Dynamic solver. We aim to use OpenACC to do so. The solver was written using fortran90 and run via terminal in linux systems. There are many directories like build,bin,cmake,src etc. in it. I started out by adding OPENACC directives to each of the source files and tried to compile using the make command in the build directory but I was getting some errors with it.

I have attached a screenshot of a section of the compiler output.
[SS of compiler output showing errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpw96.png)

Comment: Do not use screenshots for error messages. This is very important. Please copy and paste your error messages *as text*. They must be searchable by people with similar problems. See also [ask].

Comment: Also, use tag [tag:fortran] for Fortran questions. Check the short descriptions of tags you are adding.

Comment: More information will be necessary. It seems you are using CMake. Your CMake configuration is necessary. Also, run your make with `VERBOSE=1`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670121/using-cmake-with-gnu-make-how-can-i-see-the-exact-commands

Comment: Dear Vladmir, Thanks for the guidelines. I will edit my question accordingly.

Comment: Is GOACC a module that you've added?  If so, I'm guessing you just need to add the object file to the link line so the symbols can be resolved.

Comment: Yes, please don't use screenshots for code or errors. But certainly be aware that "SS" is not a good combination of letters to use in place of the word "Screenshot".

Answer (score 0):

With GCC, you'll get errors such as:

```
test.o: In function `main':
test.c:(.text.startup+0x3c): undefined reference to `GOACC_parallel_keyed'
/tmp/cc8C7CVO.crtoffloadtable.o:(.rodata+0x0): undefined reference to `__offload_func_table'
/tmp/cc8C7CVO.crtoffloadtable.o:(.rodata+0x8): undefined reference to `__offload_funcs_end'
/tmp/cc8C7CVO.crtoffloadtable.o:(.rodata+0x10): undefined reference to `__offload_var_table'
/tmp/cc8C7CVO.crtoffloadtable.o:(.rodata+0x18): undefined reference to `__offload_vars_end'
/tmp/cc0n3gC3.target.o: In function `init':
cc89TnMy.c:(.text+0x19): undefined reference to `GOMP_offload_register_ver'
/tmp/cc0n3gC3.target.o: In function `fini':
cc89TnMy.c:(.text+0x39): undefined reference to `GOMP_offload_unregister_ver'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

... if you do compile with `-fopenacc`, but don't specify the latter flag when GCC is invoked for linking.  (I suppose the build system isn't directly invoking `ld`, but instead does link via GCC.)  Thus, make sure that `-fopenacc` also is active at link time.