# Undefined references to GOACC_ symbols when linking CFD solver using OpenACC

Tags: fortran, linker-errors, openacc

I am trying to speed up an in house Computational Fluid Dynamics solver called FEST-3D by using OPENACC. I am working on a Ubuntu 22.04 Virtual Machine(on VirtualBox) with windows as host.
FEST-3D has source files written in Fortran90. I added OPENACC directives to the source files and am required to run a cmake command in the build directory of FEST3D followed by make clean and make command. It is expected to compile all the files without errors. But I ran into some error which I couldn't resolve.

A copy paste of what I did and what was the compiler's response is as follows:

```
abel@Mistborn:~/FEST-3D1$ cd build/
abel@Mistborn:~/FEST-3D1/build$ cmake ..
make cle-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/abel/FEST-3D1/build
abel@Mistborn:~/FEST-3D1/build$ make clean
abel@Mistborn:~/FEST-3D1/build$ make -j4
Scanning dependencies of target lib
[  3%] Building Fortran object ../bin/CMakeFiles/lib.dir/global/global_sst.f90.o
[  3%] Building Fortran object ../bin/CMakeFiles/lib.dir/vartypes.f90.o
[  3%] Building Fortran object ../bin/CMakeFiles/lib.dir/utils.f90.o
[  4%] Building Fortran object ../bin/CMakeFiles/lib.dir/global/global_kkl.f90.o
[  5%] Building Fortran object ../bin/CMakeFiles/lib.dir/global/global_sa.f90.o
[  7%] Building Fortran object ../bin/CMakeFiles/lib.dir/boundary/copy_bc.f90.o
[  9%] Building Fortran object ../bin/CMakeFiles/lib.dir/face/state/muscl.f90.o
[  9%] Building Fortran object ../bin/CMakeFiles/lib.dir/boundary/read_bc.f90.o
[ 10%] Building Fortran object ../bin/CMakeFiles/lib.dir/face/state/ppm.f90.o
[ 11%] Building Fortran object ../bin/CMakeFiles/lib.dir/face/state/weno.f90.o
[ 13%] Building Fortran object ../bin/CMakeFiles/lib.dir/face/state/weno_NM.f90.o
[ 14%] Building Fortran object ../bin/CMakeFiles/lib.dir/face/flux/convective/ausm.f90.o
[ 15%] Building Fortran object ../bin/CMakeFiles/lib.dir/face/flux/convective/ausmUP.f90.o
[ 16%] Building Fortran object ../bin/CMakeFiles/lib.dir/face/flux/convective/ldfss0.f90.o
[ 17%] Building Fortran object ../bin/CMakeFiles/lib.dir/face/flux/convective/slau.f90.o
[ 19%] Building Fortran object ../bin/CMakeFiles/lib.dir/face/flux/convective/van_leer.f90.o
[ 20%] Building Fortran object ../bin/CMakeFiles/lib.dir/mapping.f90.o
[ 21%] Building Fortran object ../bin/CMakeFiles/lib.dir/layout.f90.o
[ 22%] Building Fortran object ../bin/CMakeFiles/lib.dir/read_write/check_output_control.f90.o
[ 23%] Building Fortran object ../bin/CMakeFiles/lib.dir/read_write/read/read.f90.o
[ 25%] Building Fortran object ../bin/CMakeFiles/lib.dir/resnorm.f90.o
[ 26%] Building Fortran object ../bin/CMakeFiles/lib.dir/geometry.f90.o
[ 27%] Building Fortran object ../bin/CMakeFiles/lib.dir/gradients.f90.o
[ 28%] Building Fortran object ../bin/CMakeFiles/lib.dir/read_write/read/read_output_tec.f90.o
[ 29%] Building Fortran object ../bin/CMakeFiles/lib.dir/read_write/read/read_output_vtk.f90.o
[ 30%] Building Fortran object ../bin/CMakeFiles/lib.dir/wall/wall.f90.o
[ 32%] Building Fortran object ../bin/CMakeFiles/lib.dir/wall/wall_dist.f90.o
[ 33%] Building Fortran object ../bin/CMakeFiles/lib.dir/boundary/FT_bc.f90.o
[ 34%] Building Fortran object ../bin/CMakeFiles/lib.dir/boundary/bc.f90.o
[ 35%] Building Fortran object ../bin/CMakeFiles/lib.dir/face/state/face_interpolant.f90.o
[ 36%] Building Fortran object ../bin/CMakeFiles/lib.dir/grid.f90.o
[ 38%] Building Fortran object ../bin/CMakeFiles/lib.dir/interface1.f90.o
[ 39%] Building Fortran object ../bin/CMakeFiles/lib.dir/boundary/bc_primitive.f90.o
[ 40%] Building Fortran object ../bin/CMakeFiles/lib.dir/convergence.f90.o
[ 41%] Building Fortran object ../bin/CMakeFiles/lib.dir/face/flux/convective/ausmP.f90.o
[ 42%] Building Fortran object ../bin/CMakeFiles/lib.dir/read_write/read/read_output.f90.o
[ 44%] Building Fortran object ../bin/CMakeFiles/lib.dir/CC.f90.o
[ 45%] Building Fortran object ../bin/CMakeFiles/lib.dir/boundary/boundary_state_reconstruction.f90.o
[ 46%] Building Fortran object ../bin/CMakeFiles/lib.dir/viscosity.f90.o
[ 47%] Building Fortran object ../bin/CMakeFiles/lib.dir/face/flux/convective/scheme.f90.o
[ 48%] Building Fortran object ../bin/CMakeFiles/lib.dir/state.f90.o
[ 51%] Building Fortran object ../bin/CMakeFiles/lib.dir/forces.f90.o
[ 51%] Building Fortran object ../bin/CMakeFiles/lib.dir/lusgs.f90.o
[ 52%] Building Fortran object ../bin/CMakeFiles/lib.dir/plusgs.f90.o
[ 53%] Building Fortran object ../bin/CMakeFiles/lib.dir/read_write/write/write_output_tec.f90.o
[ 54%] Building Fortran object ../bin/CMakeFiles/lib.dir/read_write/write/write_output_tec_node.f90.o
[ 55%] Building Fortran object ../bin/CMakeFiles/lib.dir/read_write/write/write_output_vtk.f90.o
[ 57%] Building Fortran object ../bin/CMakeFiles/lib.dir/time.f90.o
[ 58%] Building Fortran object ../bin/CMakeFiles/lib.dir/source.f90.o
[ 59%] Building Fortran object ../bin/CMakeFiles/lib.dir/viscous.f90.o
[ 60%] Building Fortran object ../bin/CMakeFiles/lib.dir/read_write/write/write_output.f90.o
[ 61%] Building Fortran object ../bin/CMakeFiles/lib.dir/read_write/write/dump_solution.f90.o
[ 63%] Building Fortran object ../bin/CMakeFiles/lib.dir/update.f90.o
[ 64%] Building Fortran object ../bin/CMakeFiles/lib.dir/solver.f90.o
[ 64%] Built target lib
Scanning dependencies of target FEST3D
Scanning dependencies of target testsuite_fortran
[ 65%] Building Fortran object ../bin/CMakeFiles/FEST3D.dir/main.f90.o
[ 69%] Building Fortran object tests/CMakeFiles/testsuite_fortran.dir/test_alloc.f90.o
[ 69%] Building Fortran object tests/CMakeFiles/testsuite_fortran.dir/test_layout.f90.o
[ 69%] Building Fortran object tests/CMakeFiles/testsuite_fortran.dir/test_mpi.f90.o
[ 70%] Building Fortran object tests/CMakeFiles/testsuite_fortran.dir/test_grid.f90.o
[ 71%] Building Fortran object tests/CMakeFiles/testsuite_fortran.dir/test_geometry.f90.o
[ 72%] Linking Fortran executable FEST3D
[ 73%] Building Fortran object tests/CMakeFiles/testsuite_fortran.dir/test_read.f90.o
[ 75%] Building Fortran object tests/CMakeFiles/testsuite_fortran.dir/test_state.f90.o
[ 76%] Building Fortran object tests/CMakeFiles/testsuite_fortran.dir/test_gradient.f90.o
[ 77%] Building Fortran object tests/CMakeFiles/testsuite_fortran.dir/test_viscosity.f90.o
[ 78%] Building Fortran object tests/CMakeFiles/testsuite_fortran.dir/test_first_order.f90.o
[ 79%] Building Fortran object tests/CMakeFiles/testsuite_fortran.dir/test_muscl.f90.o
[ 79%] Built target FEST3D
[ 80%] Building Fortran object tests/CMakeFiles/testsuite_fortran.dir/test_ppm.f90.o
[ 82%] Building Fortran object tests/CMakeFiles/testsuite_fortran.dir/test_weno.f90.o
[ 83%] Building Fortran object tests/CMakeFiles/testsuite_fortran.dir/test_weno_NM.f90.o
[ 84%] Building Fortran object tests/CMakeFiles/testsuite_fortran.dir/test_ausm.f90.o
[ 85%] Building Fortran object tests/CMakeFiles/testsuite_fortran.dir/test_ausmp.f90.o
[ 86%] Building Fortran object tests/CMakeFiles/testsuite_fortran.dir/test_ausmUP.f90.o
[ 88%] Building Fortran object tests/CMakeFiles/testsuite_fortran.dir/test_slau.f90.o
[ 89%] Building Fortran object tests/CMakeFiles/testsuite_fortran.dir/test_ldfss.f90.o
[ 90%] Building Fortran object tests/CMakeFiles/testsuite_fortran.dir/test_van_leer.f90.o
[ 91%] Building Fortran object tests/CMakeFiles/testsuite_fortran.dir/test_residue.f90.o
[ 92%] Building Fortran object tests/CMakeFiles/testsuite_fortran.dir/test_bc.f90.o
[ 94%] Building Fortran object tests/CMakeFiles/testsuite_fortran.dir/test_time.f90.o
[ 95%] Building Fortran object tests/CMakeFiles/testsuite_fortran.dir/test_convergence.f90.o
[ 96%] Building Fortran object tests/CMakeFiles/testsuite_fortran.dir/test_succeeds_1.f90.o
[ 97%] Linking Fortran static library libtestsuite_fortran.a
[ 97%] Built target testsuite_fortran
[ 98%] Building C object tests/CMakeFiles/testsuite.dir/main.c.o
[100%] Linking C executable testsuite
/usr/bin/ld: libtestsuite_fortran.a(resnorm.f90.o): in function `__resnorm_MOD_find_resnorm':
resnorm.f90:(.text+0x330b): undefined reference to `GOACC_parallel_keyed'
/usr/bin/ld: resnorm.f90:(.text+0x401e): undefined reference to `GOACC_data_start'
/usr/bin/ld: resnorm.f90:(.text+0x4167): undefined reference to `GOACC_parallel_keyed'
/usr/bin/ld: resnorm.f90:(.text+0x416c): undefined reference to `GOACC_data_end'
/usr/bin/ld: libtestsuite_fortran.a(mapping.f90.o): in function `__mapping_MOD_read_interface_map':
mapping.f90:(.text+0xb44): undefined reference to `GOACC_parallel_keyed'
/usr/bin/ld: libtestsuite_fortran.a(geometry.f90.o): in function `__geometry_MOD_allocate_memory':
geometry.f90:(.text+0x244): undefined reference to `GOACC_enter_exit_data'
/usr/bin/ld: geometry.f90:(.text+0x9f0): undefined reference to `GOACC_update'
/usr/bin/ld: libtestsuite_fortran.a(geometry.f90.o): in function `__geometry_MOD_normalize_face_normals':
geometry.f90:(.text+0x1412): undefined reference to `GOACC_parallel_keyed'
/usr/bin/ld: geometry.f90:(.text+0x158b): undefined reference to `GOACC_parallel_keyed'
/usr/bin/ld: geometry.f90:(.text+0x1716): undefined reference to `GOACC_parallel_keyed'
/usr/bin/ld: libtestsuite_fortran.a(geometry.f90.o): in function `__geometry_MOD_compute_face_area_vectors':
geometry.f90:(.text+0xa72e): undefined reference to `GOACC_parallel_keyed'
/usr/bin/ld: geometry.f90:(.text+0xaa86): undefined reference to `GOACC_parallel_keyed'
/usr/bin/ld: libtestsuite_fortran.a(geometry.f90.o):geometry.f90:(.text+0xadcc): more undefined references to `GOACC_parallel_keyed' follow
/usr/bin/ld: libtestsuite_fortran.a(gradients.f90.o): in function `__gradients_MOD_apply_gradient_bc_face':
gradients.f90:(.text+0x5680): undefined reference to `GOACC_data_start'
/usr/bin/ld: gradients.f90:(.text+0x5e46): undefined reference to `GOACC_parallel_keyed'
/usr/bin/ld: gradients.f90:(.text+0x5e4b): undefined reference to `GOACC_data_end'
/usr/bin/ld: libtestsuite_fortran.a(gradients.f90.o): in function `__gradients_MOD_compute_gradient_g':
gradients.f90:(.text+0x67d0): undefined reference to `GOACC_data_start'
/usr/bin/ld: gradients.f90:(.text+0x6b7a): undefined reference to `GOACC_parallel_keyed'
/usr/bin/ld: gradients.f90:(.text+0x6b7f): undefined reference to `GOACC_data_end'
/usr/bin/ld: gradients.f90:(.text+0x6cef): undefined reference to `GOACC_data_start'
/usr/bin/ld: gradients.f90:(.text+0x71fa): undefined reference to `GOACC_data_start'
/usr/bin/ld: libtestsuite_fortran.a(wall_dist.f90.o): in function `__wall_dist_MOD_read_destroy_nodefile':
wall_dist.f90:(.text+0x928): undefined reference to `GOACC_parallel_keyed'
/usr/bin/ld: libtestsuite_fortran.a(wall_dist.f90.o): in function `__wall_dist_MOD_find_wall_dist':
wall_dist.f90:(.text+0xd48): undefined reference to `GOACC_parallel_keyed'
/usr/bin/ld: wall_dist.f90:(.text+0xe89): undefined reference to `GOACC_parallel_keyed'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [tests/CMakeFiles/testsuite.dir/build.make:98: tests/testsuite] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:225: tests/CMakeFiles/testsuite.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:101: all] Error 2
```

As can be seen, after the " [100%] Linking C executable testsuite " line, the compiler returned errors, which I couldn't resolve. The .f90 files which are mentioned is present in the src folder of FEST-3D.

The output displayed by the compiler when I run make VERBOSE=1 is as follows:

```
abel@Mistborn:~/FEST-3D1/build$ make VERBOSE=1
/usr/bin/cmake -S/home/abel/FEST-3D1 -B/home/abel/FEST-3D1/build --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /home/abel/FEST-3D1/build/CMakeFiles /home/abel/FEST-3D1/build//CMakeFiles/progress.marks
make  -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/abel/FEST-3D1/build'
make  -f ../bin/CMakeFiles/lib.dir/build.make ../bin/CMakeFiles/lib.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/abel/FEST-3D1/build'
cd /home/abel/FEST-3D1/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/abel/FEST-3D1 /home/abel/FEST-3D1/src /home/abel/FEST-3D1/build /home/abel/FEST-3D1/bin /home/abel/FEST-3D1/bin/CMakeFiles/lib.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/abel/FEST-3D1/build'
make  -f ../bin/CMakeFiles/lib.dir/build.make ../bin/CMakeFiles/lib.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/abel/FEST-3D1/build'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for '../bin/CMakeFiles/lib.dir/build'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/abel/FEST-3D1/build'
[ 64%] Built target lib
make  -f ../bin/CMakeFiles/FEST3D.dir/build.make ../bin/CMakeFiles/FEST3D.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/abel/FEST-3D1/build'
cd /home/abel/FEST-3D1/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/abel/FEST-3D1 /home/abel/FEST-3D1/src /home/abel/FEST-3D1/build /home/abel/FEST-3D1/bin /home/abel/FEST-3D1/bin/CMakeFiles/FEST3D.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/abel/FEST-3D1/build'
make  -f ../bin/CMakeFiles/FEST3D.dir/build.make ../bin/CMakeFiles/FEST3D.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/abel/FEST-3D1/build'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for '../bin/CMakeFiles/FEST3D.dir/build'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/abel/FEST-3D1/build'
[ 66%] Built target FEST3D
make  -f tests/CMakeFiles/testsuite_fortran.dir/build.make tests/CMakeFiles/testsuite_fortran.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/abel/FEST-3D1/build'
cd /home/abel/FEST-3D1/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/abel/FEST-3D1 /home/abel/FEST-3D1/tests /home/abel/FEST-3D1/build /home/abel/FEST-3D1/build/tests /home/abel/FEST-3D1/build/tests/CMakeFiles/testsuite_fortran.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/abel/FEST-3D1/build'
make  -f tests/CMakeFiles/testsuite_fortran.dir/build.make tests/CMakeFiles/testsuite_fortran.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/abel/FEST-3D1/build'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'tests/CMakeFiles/testsuite_fortran.dir/build'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/abel/FEST-3D1/build'
[ 97%] Built target testsuite_fortran
make  -f tests/CMakeFiles/testsuite.dir/build.make tests/CMakeFiles/testsuite.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/abel/FEST-3D1/build'
cd /home/abel/FEST-3D1/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/abel/FEST-3D1 /home/abel/FEST-3D1/tests /home/abel/FEST-3D1/build /home/abel/FEST-3D1/build/tests /home/abel/FEST-3D1/build/tests/CMakeFiles/testsuite.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
Dependencies file "tests/CMakeFiles/testsuite.dir/main.c.o.d" is newer than depends file "/home/abel/FEST-3D1/build/tests/CMakeFiles/testsuite.dir/compiler_depend.internal".
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target testsuite
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/abel/FEST-3D1/build'
make  -f tests/CMakeFiles/testsuite.dir/build.make tests/CMakeFiles/testsuite.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/abel/FEST-3D1/build'
[ 98%] Linking C executable testsuite
cd /home/abel/FEST-3D1/build/tests && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/testsuite.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc -O3 -DNDEBUG CMakeFiles/testsuite.dir/main.c.o -o testsuite   -L/opt/mpich1/lib  libtestsuite_fortran.a -lmpifort -lmpi -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -lm 
/usr/bin/ld: libtestsuite_fortran.a(resnorm.f90.o): in function `__resnorm_MOD_find_resnorm':
resnorm.f90:(.text+0x330b): undefined reference to `GOACC_parallel_keyed'
/usr/bin/ld: resnorm.f90:(.text+0x401e): undefined reference to `GOACC_data_start'
/usr/bin/ld: resnorm.f90:(.text+0x4167): undefined reference to `GOACC_parallel_keyed'
/usr/bin/ld: resnorm.f90:(.text+0x416c): undefined reference to `GOACC_data_end'
/usr/bin/ld: libtestsuite_fortran.a(mapping.f90.o): in function `__mapping_MOD_read_interface_map':
mapping.f90:(.text+0xb44): undefined reference to `GOACC_parallel_keyed'
/usr/bin/ld: libtestsuite_fortran.a(geometry.f90.o): in function `__geometry_MOD_allocate_memory':
geometry.f90:(.text+0x244): undefined reference to `GOACC_enter_exit_data'
/usr/bin/ld: geometry.f90:(.text+0x9f0): undefined reference to `GOACC_update'
/usr/bin/ld: libtestsuite_fortran.a(geometry.f90.o): in function `__geometry_MOD_normalize_face_normals':
geometry.f90:(.text+0x1412): undefined reference to `GOACC_parallel_keyed'
/usr/bin/ld: geometry.f90:(.text+0x158b): undefined reference to `GOACC_parallel_keyed'
/usr/bin/ld: geometry.f90:(.text+0x1716): undefined reference to `GOACC_parallel_keyed'
/usr/bin/ld: libtestsuite_fortran.a(geometry.f90.o): in function `__geometry_MOD_compute_face_area_vectors':
geometry.f90:(.text+0xa72e): undefined reference to `GOACC_parallel_keyed'
/usr/bin/ld: geometry.f90:(.text+0xaa86): undefined reference to `GOACC_parallel_keyed'
/usr/bin/ld: libtestsuite_fortran.a(geometry.f90.o):geometry.f90:(.text+0xadcc): more undefined references to `GOACC_parallel_keyed' follow
/usr/bin/ld: libtestsuite_fortran.a(gradients.f90.o): in function `__gradients_MOD_apply_gradient_bc_face':
gradients.f90:(.text+0x5680): undefined reference to `GOACC_data_start'
/usr/bin/ld: gradients.f90:(.text+0x5e46): undefined reference to `GOACC_parallel_keyed'
/usr/bin/ld: gradients.f90:(.text+0x5e4b): undefined reference to `GOACC_data_end'
/usr/bin/ld: libtestsuite_fortran.a(gradients.f90.o): in function `__gradients_MOD_compute_gradient_g':
gradients.f90:(.text+0x67d0): undefined reference to `GOACC_data_start'
/usr/bin/ld: gradients.f90:(.text+0x6b7a): undefined reference to `GOACC_parallel_keyed'
/usr/bin/ld: gradients.f90:(.text+0x6b7f): undefined reference to `GOACC_data_end'
/usr/bin/ld: gradients.f90:(.text+0x6cef): undefined reference to `GOACC_data_start'
/usr/bin/ld: gradients.f90:(.text+0x71fa): undefined reference to `GOACC_data_start'
/usr/bin/ld: libtestsuite_fortran.a(wall_dist.f90.o): in function `__wall_dist_MOD_read_destroy_nodefile':
wall_dist.f90:(.text+0x928): undefined reference to `GOACC_parallel_keyed'
/usr/bin/ld: libtestsuite_fortran.a(wall_dist.f90.o): in function `__wall_dist_MOD_find_wall_dist':
wall_dist.f90:(.text+0xd48): undefined reference to `GOACC_parallel_keyed'
/usr/bin/ld: wall_dist.f90:(.text+0xe89): undefined reference to `GOACC_parallel_keyed'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [tests/CMakeFiles/testsuite.dir/build.make:98: tests/testsuite] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/abel/FEST-3D1/build'
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:225: tests/CMakeFiles/testsuite.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/abel/FEST-3D1/build'
make: *** [Makefile:101: all] Error 2
```

The contents of the SetFortranFlags.cmake file in the cmake directory is as shown:

```
######################################################
# Determine and set the Fortran compiler flags we want 
######################################################

####################################################################
# Make sure that the default build type is RELEASE if not specified.
####################################################################
INCLUDE(${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH}/SetCompileFlag.cmake)

# Make sure the build type is uppercase
STRING(TOUPPER "${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}" BT)

IF(BT STREQUAL "RELEASE")
    SET(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE RELEASE CACHE STRING
      "Choose the type of build, options are DEBUG, RELEASE, or TESTING."
      FORCE)
ELSEIF(BT STREQUAL "DEBUG")
    SET (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE DEBUG CACHE STRING
      "Choose the type of build, options are DEBUG, RELEASE, or TESTING."
      FORCE)
ELSEIF(BT STREQUAL "TESTING")
    SET (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE TESTING CACHE STRING
      "Choose the type of build, options are DEBUG, RELEASE, or TESTING."
      FORCE)
ELSEIF(NOT BT)
    SET(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE RELEASE CACHE STRING
      "Choose the type of build, options are DEBUG, RELEASE, or TESTING."
      FORCE)
    MESSAGE(STATUS "CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE not given, defaulting to RELEASE")
ELSE()
    MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR "CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE not valid, choices are DEBUG, RELEASE, or TESTING")
ENDIF(BT STREQUAL "RELEASE")

#########################################################
# If the compiler flags have already been set, return now
#########################################################

IF(CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_RELEASE AND CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_TESTING AND CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_DEBUG)
    RETURN ()
ENDIF(CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_RELEASE AND CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_TESTING AND CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_DEBUG)

########################################################################
# Determine the appropriate flags for this compiler for each build type.
# For each option type, a list of possible flags is given that work
# for various compilers.  The first flag that works is chosen.
# If none of the flags work, nothing is added (unless the REQUIRED 
# flag is given in the call).  This way unknown compiles are supported.
#######################################################################

#####################
### GENERAL FLAGS ###
#####################

## Orignal intent: Don't add underscores in symbols for C-compatability
## However, this following flag is not being used because 
## of incomptibilty issue created for MacOSX
#SET_COMPILE_FLAG(CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS "${CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS}"
#                 Fortran "-fno-underscoring")

# There is some bug where -march=native doesn't work on Mac
IF(APPLE)
    SET(GNUNATIVE "-mtune=native")
ELSE()
    SET(GNUNATIVE "-march=native")
ENDIF()
# Optimize for the host's architecture
SET_COMPILE_FLAG(CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS "${CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS}"
                 Fortran "-xHost"        # Intel
                         "/QxHost"       # Intel Windows
                         ${GNUNATIVE}    # GNU
                         "-ta=host"      # Portland Group
                )

# preprocessor
SET_COMPILE_FLAG(CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS "${CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS}"
                 Fortran "-cpp"        Intel # Intel/GNU
                )

# double precision
SET_COMPILE_FLAG(CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS "${CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS}"
                 Fortran "-r8"              # Intel
                         "-fdefault-real-8" # GNU
                )

# Set Free format
SET_COMPILE_FLAG(CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS "${CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS}"
                 Fortran "-ffree-line-length-256" #GNU
                         "-extend_soruce"                 #Intel
                 )

# fpic
SET_COMPILE_FLAG(CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS "${CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS}"
                Fortran "-fPIC"        Intel # Intel/GNU
                )
###################
### DEBUG FLAGS ###
###################

# NOTE: debugging symbols (-g or /debug:full) are already on by default

# Disable optimizations
SET_COMPILE_FLAG(CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_DEBUG}"
                 Fortran REQUIRED "-O0" # All compilers not on Windows
                                  "/Od" # Intel Windows
                )

# Turn on all warnings 
SET_COMPILE_FLAG(CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_DEBUG}"
                 Fortran "-warn all" # Intel
                         "/warn:all" # Intel Windows
                         "-Wall"     # GNU
                                     # Portland Group (on by default)
                )

# Traceback
SET_COMPILE_FLAG(CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_DEBUG}"
                 Fortran "-traceback"   # Intel/Portland Group
                         "/traceback"   # Intel Windows
                         "-fbacktrace"  # GNU (gfortran)
                         "-ftrace=full" # GNU (g95)
                )

# Check array bounds
SET_COMPILE_FLAG(CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_DEBUG}"
                 Fortran "-check all"  # Intel
                         "/check:bounds"  # Intel Windows
                         "-fcheck=bounds" # GNU (New style)
                         "-fbounds-check" # GNU (Old style)
                         "-Mbounds"       # Portland Group
                )

SET_COMPILE_FLAG(CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_DEBUG}"
                 Fortran "-I_MPI_HYDRA_DEBUG=1" #intel
                 )
#####################
### TESTING FLAGS ###
#####################

# Optimizations
SET_COMPILE_FLAG(CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_TESTING "${CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_TESTING}"
                 Fortran REQUIRED "-O2" # All compilers not on Windows
                                  "/O2" # Intel Windows
                )

#####################
### RELEASE FLAGS ###
#####################

# NOTE: agressive optimizations (-O3) are already turned on by default

# Unroll loops
SET_COMPILE_FLAG(CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_RELEASE}"
                 Fortran "-funroll-loops" # GNU
                         "-unroll"        # Intel
                         "/unroll"        # Intel Windows
                         "-Munroll"       # Portland Group
                )

# Inline functions
SET_COMPILE_FLAG(CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_RELEASE}"
                 Fortran "-inline"            # Intel
                         "/Qinline"           # Intel Windows
                         "-finline-functions" # GNU
                         "-Minline"           # Portland Group
                )

# Single-file optimizations
SET_COMPILE_FLAG(CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_RELEASE}"
                 Fortran "-ip"  # Intel
                         "/Qip" # Intel Windows
                )
                
# Add -fopenacc flag
SET_COMPILE_FLAG(CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_RELEASE}"
                 Fortran "-fopenacc"
                )
```

Here, the last part starting with "# Add -fopenacc flag" is what I added. Is there any mistake in that? Or should I add the flag elsewhere?

It would be really helpful if someone can help me with this as I am quite new to OPENACC. If further info is needed, kindly ask and Ill provide it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66855252/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix and searching for similar errors in existing questions. The error message is rarely sufficient. We must know which exact commands does your CMake run. Run it in the verbose mode using `make VERBOSE=1`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670121/using-cmake-with-gnu-make-how-can-i-see-the-exact-commands

Comment: Remember the answer to your last question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76933719/undefined-reference-to-goacc-parallel-keyed-and-related-errors-coming-up-wh We really need to see the exact commands you are running, even if you are running them through CMake and make.

Comment: An educated guess, which would benefit from seeing the output of `make VERBOSE=1`, but it's possible the flag to enable OpenACC support is only getting passed at compile-time, but not link-time, resulting in the OpenACC runtime being left off of the final link step.

Comment: @jefflarkin Yes, that was exactly the conclusion of the last question I linked.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions @VladimirFГероямслава. I have edited my question by adding the output of make VERBOSE=1

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @jefflarkin. I have edited the question by adding the output of make VERBOSE=1.

Comment: Indeed, there is no `-fopenacc` in your `cc` limking command and the answer is the same as in  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76933719/undefined-reference-to-goacc-parallel-keyed-and-related-errors-coming-up-wh

Comment: If you want to get advice how to fix your make configuration, you really have to show the configuration first, otherwise no-one can say where exactly you should change it.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава, sure, I'll edit my question by adding the "SetFortranFlags.cmake" file from the cmake directory.

Comment: That is probably not enough. Note that the linking is done using `cc`.

Comment: I am not familiar with using cc. Should I add it to the cmake file?

Comment: No, you should show the complete cmake configuration. `cc` is already being used in `/usr/bin/cc -O3 -DNDEBUG CMakeFiles/testsuite.dir/main.c.o -o testsuite ...`

Comment: I closed the question as a duplicate. The answer is really to add the `-fopenacc` to the link command. Without the complete CMake configuration we cannot tell you what you specifically should change because we cannot see your files.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add also the -fopenacc flag at link time to allow your compiler to call ld with the right libraries.

Comment: Yes, this was quite clear in the comments and in the previous answer the asker got in their previous question. The open problem was, how to do that in their CMake configuration. Unfortunatelly, the OP never revealed the relevant configuration files they currently use.