# C++/STD - error: 'path' is unavailable: introduced in macOS 10.15

Tags: c++, filesystems, std

I am building [QCefView](https://github.com/CefView/QCefView) on my MacBook M2 Max, MacOS 13.5 Ventura.

Here is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(CEFTest VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(QT NAMES Qt6 Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets)
find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets)
add_subdirectory(QCefView)

set(PROJECT_SOURCES
        main.cpp
        mainwindow.cpp
        mainwindow.h
        mainwindow.ui
)

if(${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} GREATER_EQUAL 6)
    qt_add_executable(CEFTest
        MANUAL_FINALIZATION
        ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
    )
# Define target properties for Android with Qt 6 as:
#    set_property(TARGET CEFTest APPEND PROPERTY QT_ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR
#                 ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/android)
# For more information, see https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt-add-executable.html#target-creation
else()
    if(ANDROID)
        add_library(CEFTest SHARED
            ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
        )
# Define properties for Android with Qt 5 after find_package() calls as:
#    set(ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/android")
    else()
        add_executable(CEFTest
            ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
        )
    endif()
endif()

target_link_libraries(CEFTest PRIVATE Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Widgets)

# Qt for iOS sets MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER automatically since Qt 6.1.
# If you are developing for iOS or macOS you should consider setting an
# explicit, fixed bundle identifier manually though.
if(${QT_VERSION} VERSION_LESS 6.1.0)
  set(BUNDLE_ID_OPTION MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER com.example.CEFTest)
endif()
set_target_properties(CEFTest PROPERTIES
    ${BUNDLE_ID_OPTION}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_SHORT_VERSION_STRING ${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE TRUE
    WIN32_EXECUTABLE TRUE
)

include(GNUInstallDirs)
install(TARGETS CEFTest
    BUNDLE DESTINATION .
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
)

if(QT_VERSION_MAJOR EQUAL 6)
    qt_finalize_executable(CEFTest)
endif()
```

While building I get this error:

```
[ 95%] Building CXX object QCefView/src/CMakeFiles/QCefView.dir/details/QCefConfigPrivate.cpp.o
In file included from /Users/venelin/Development/CEFTest/CEFTest/QCefView/src/details/QCefConfigPrivate.cpp:5:
In file included from /Users/venelin/Qt/6.6.0/macos/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/QDir:1:
In file included from /Users/venelin/Qt/6.6.0/macos/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qdir.h:8:
/Users/venelin/Qt/6.6.0/macos/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qfile.h:59:58: error: 'path' is unavailable: introduced in macOS 10.15
inline QString fromFilesystemPath(const std::filesystem::path &path)
                                                         ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.0.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/filesystem:909:24: note: 'path' has been explicitly marked unavailable here
class _LIBCPP_TYPE_VIS path {
                       ^
In file included from /Users/venelin/Development/CEFTest/CEFTest/QCefView/src/details/QCefConfigPrivate.cpp:5:
In file included from /Users/venelin/Qt/6.6.0/macos/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/QDir:1:
In file included from /Users/venelin/Qt/6.6.0/macos/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qdir.h:8:
/Users/venelin/Qt/6.6.0/macos/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qfile.h:64:40: error: 'native' is unavailable: introduced in macOS 10.15
    return QString::fromStdString(path.native());
                                       ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.0.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/filesystem:1193:22: note: 'native' has been explicitly marked unavailable here
  const string_type& native() const noexcept { return __pn_; }
                     ^
In file included from /Users/venelin/Development/CEFTest/CEFTest/QCefView/src/details/QCefConfigPrivate.cpp:5:
In file included from /Users/venelin/Qt/6.6.0/macos/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/QDir:1:
In file included from /Users/venelin/Qt/6.6.0/macos/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qdir.h:8:
/Users/venelin/Qt/6.6.0/macos/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qfile.h:68:25: error: 'path' is unavailable: introduced in macOS 10.15
inline std::filesystem::path toFilesystemPath(const QString &path)
                        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.0.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/filesystem:909:24: note: 'path' has been explicitly marked unavailable here
class _LIBCPP_TYPE_VIS path {
                       ^
In file included from /Users/venelin/Development/CEFTest/CEFTest/QCefView/src/details/QCefConfigPrivate.cpp:5:
In file included from /Users/venelin/Qt/6.6.0/macos/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/QDir:1:
In file included from /Users/venelin/Qt/6.6.0/macos/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qdir.h:8:
/Users/venelin/Qt/6.6.0/macos/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qfile.h:70:29: error: 'path' is unavailable: introduced in macOS 10.15
    return std::filesystem::path(reinterpret_cast<const char16_t *>(path.cbegin()),
                            ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.0.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/filesystem:909:24: note: 'path' has been explicitly marked unavailable here
class _LIBCPP_TYPE_VIS path {
                       ^
In file included from /Users/venelin/Development/CEFTest/CEFTest/QCefView/src/details/QCefConfigPrivate.cpp:5:
In file included from /Users/venelin/Qt/6.6.0/macos/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/QDir:1:
In file included from /Users/venelin/Qt/6.6.0/macos/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qdir.h:8:
/Users/venelin/Qt/6.6.0/macos/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qfile.h:70:12: error: 'path<const char16_t *>' is unavailable: introduced in macOS 10.15
    return std::filesystem::path(reinterpret_cast<const char16_t *>(path.cbegin()),
           ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.0.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/filesystem:953:3: note: 'path<const char16_t *>' has been explicitly marked unavailable here
  path(_InputIt __first, _InputIt __last, format = format::auto_format) {
  ^
In file included from /Users/venelin/Development/CEFTest/CEFTest/QCefView/src/details/QCefConfigPrivate.cpp:5:
In file included from /Users/venelin/Qt/6.6.0/macos/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/QDir:1:
In file included from /Users/venelin/Qt/6.6.0/macos/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qdir.h:8:
/Users/venelin/Qt/6.6.0/macos/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qfile.h:70:12: error: 'path' is unavailable: introduced in macOS 10.15
    return std::filesystem::path(reinterpret_cast<const char16_t *>(path.cbegin()),
           ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.0.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/filesystem:953:3: note: 'path' has been explicitly marked unavailable here
  path(_InputIt __first, _InputIt __last, format = format::auto_format) {
  ^
In file included from /Users/venelin/Development/CEFTest/CEFTest/QCefView/src/details/QCefConfigPrivate.cpp:5:
In file included from /Users/venelin/Qt/6.6.0/macos/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/QDir:1:
In file included from /Users/venelin/Qt/6.6.0/macos/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qdir.h:8:
/Users/venelin/Qt/6.6.0/macos/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qfile.h:70:12: error: '~path' is unavailable: introduced in macOS 10.15
    return std::filesystem::path(reinterpret_cast<const char16_t *>(path.cbegin()),
           ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.0.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/filesystem:968:3: note: '~path' has been explicitly marked unavailable here
  ~path() = default;
  ^
In file included from /Users/venelin/Development/CEFTest/CEFTest/QCefView/src/details/QCefConfigPrivate.cpp:5:
In file included from /Users/venelin/Qt/6.6.0/macos/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/QDir:1:
In file included from /Users/venelin/Qt/6.6.0/macos/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qdir.h:8:
/Users/venelin/Qt/6.6.0/macos/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qfile.h:128:22: error: 'path' is unavailable: introduced in macOS 10.15
    std::filesystem::path filesystemFileName() const
                     ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.0.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/filesystem:909:24: note: 'path' has been explicitly marked unavailable here
class _LIBCPP_TYPE_VIS path {
                       ^
In file included from /Users/venelin/Development/CEFTest/CEFTest/QCefView/src/details/QCefConfigPrivate.cpp:5:
In file included from /Users/venelin/Qt/6.6.0/macos/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/QDir:1:
In file included from /Users/venelin/Qt/6.6.0/macos/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qdir.h:8:
/Users/venelin/Qt/6.6.0/macos/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qfile.h:190:22: error: 'path' is unavailable: introduced in macOS 10.15
    std::filesystem::path filesystemSymLinkTarget() const
                     ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.0.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/filesystem:909:24: note: 'path' has been explicitly marked unavailable here
class _LIBCPP_TYPE_VIS path {
                       ^
In file included from /Users/venelin/Development/CEFTest/CEFTest/QCefView/src/details/QCefConfigPrivate.cpp:5:
In file included from /Users/venelin/Qt/6.6.0/macos/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/QDir:1:
In file included from /Users/venelin/Qt/6.6.0/macos/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qdir.h:8:
/Users/venelin/Qt/6.6.0/macos/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qfile.h:195:29: error: 'path' is unavailable: introduced in macOS 10.15
    static std::filesystem::path filesystemSymLinkTarget(const T &fileName)
                            ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.0.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/filesystem:909:24: note: 'path' has been explicitly marked unavailable here
class _LIBCPP_TYPE_VIS path {
                       ^
In file included from /Users/venelin/Development/CEFTest/CEFTest/QCefView/src/details/QCefConfigPrivate.cpp:5:
In file included from /Users/venelin/Qt/6.6.0/macos/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/QDir:1:
In file included from /Users/venelin/Qt/6.6.0/macos/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qdir.h:8:
/Users/venelin/Qt/6.6.0/macos/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qfile.h:129:14: error: '~path' is unavailable: introduced in macOS 10.15
    { return QtPrivate::toFilesystemPath(fileName()); }
             ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.0.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/filesystem:968:3: note: '~path' has been explicitly marked unavailable here
  ~path() = default;
  ^
In file included from /Users/venelin/Development/CEFTest/CEFTest/QCefView/src/details/QCefConfigPrivate.cpp:5:
In file included from /Users/venelin/Qt/6.6.0/macos/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/QDir:1:
In file included from /Users/venelin/Qt/6.6.0/macos/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qdir.h:8:
/Users/venelin/Qt/6.6.0/macos/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qfile.h:192:16: error: '~path' is unavailable: introduced in macOS 10.15
        return QtPrivate::toFilesystemPath(symLinkTarget());
               ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.0.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/filesystem:968:3: note: '~path' has been explicitly marked unavailable here
  ~path() = default;
  ^
In file included from /Users/venelin/Development/CEFTest/CEFTest/QCefView/src/details/QCefConfigPrivate.cpp:5:
In file included from /Users/venelin/Qt/6.6.0/macos/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/QDir:1:
In file included from /Users/venelin/Qt/6.6.0/macos/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qdir.h:9:
/Users/venelin/Qt/6.6.0/macos/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qfileinfo.h:82:22: error: 'path' is unavailable: introduced in macOS 10.15
    std::filesystem::path filesystemFilePath() const
                     ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.0.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/filesystem:909:24: note: 'path' has been explicitly marked unavailable here
class _LIBCPP_TYPE_VIS path {
                       ^
In file included from /Users/venelin/Development/CEFTest/CEFTest/QCefView/src/details/QCefConfigPrivate.cpp:5:
In file included from /Users/venelin/Qt/6.6.0/macos/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/QDir:1:
In file included from /Users/venelin/Qt/6.6.0/macos/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qdir.h:9:
/Users/venelin/Qt/6.6.0/macos/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qfileinfo.h:84:22: error: 'path' is unavailable: introduced in macOS 10.15
    std::filesystem::path filesystemAbsoluteFilePath() const
                     ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.0.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/filesystem:909:24: note: 'path' has been explicitly marked unavailable here
class _LIBCPP_TYPE_VIS path {
                       ^
In file included from /Users/venelin/Development/CEFTest/CEFTest/QCefView/src/details/QCefConfigPrivate.cpp:5:
In file included from /Users/venelin/Qt/6.6.0/macos/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/QDir:1:
In file included from /Users/venelin/Qt/6.6.0/macos/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qdir.h:9:
/Users/venelin/Qt/6.6.0/macos/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qfileinfo.h:86:22: error: 'path' is unavailable: introduced in macOS 10.15
    std::filesystem::path filesystemCanonicalFilePath() const
                     ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.0.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/filesystem:909:24: note: 'path' has been explicitly marked unavailable here
class _LIBCPP_TYPE_VIS path {
                       ^
In file included from /Users/venelin/Development/CEFTest/CEFTest/QCefView/src/details/QCefConfigPrivate.cpp:5:
In file included from /Users/venelin/Qt/6.6.0/macos/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/QDir:1:
In file included from /Users/venelin/Qt/6.6.0/macos/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qdir.h:9:
/Users/venelin/Qt/6.6.0/macos/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qfileinfo.h:100:22: error: 'path' is unavailable: introduced in macOS 10.15
    std::filesystem::path filesystemPath() const { return QtPrivate::toFilesystemPath(path()); }
                     ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.0.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/filesystem:909:24: note: 'path' has been explicitly marked unavailable here
class _LIBCPP_TYPE_VIS path {
                       ^
In file included from /Users/venelin/Development/CEFTest/CEFTest/QCefView/src/details/QCefConfigPrivate.cpp:5:
In file included from /Users/venelin/Qt/6.6.0/macos/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/QDir:1:
In file included from /Users/venelin/Qt/6.6.0/macos/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qdir.h:9:
/Users/venelin/Qt/6.6.0/macos/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qfileinfo.h:101:22: error: 'path' is unavailable: introduced in macOS 10.15
    std::filesystem::path filesystemAbsolutePath() const
                     ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.0.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/filesystem:909:24: note: 'path' has been explicitly marked unavailable here
class _LIBCPP_TYPE_VIS path {
                       ^
In file included from /Users/venelin/Development/CEFTest/CEFTest/QCefView/src/details/QCefConfigPrivate.cpp:5:
In file included from /Users/venelin/Qt/6.6.0/macos/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/QDir:1:
In file included from /Users/venelin/Qt/6.6.0/macos/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qdir.h:9:
/Users/venelin/Qt/6.6.0/macos/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qfileinfo.h:103:22: error: 'path' is unavailable: introduced in macOS 10.15
    std::filesystem::path filesystemCanonicalPath() const
                     ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.0.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/filesystem:909:24: note: 'path' has been explicitly marked unavailable here
class _LIBCPP_TYPE_VIS path {
                       ^
In file included from /Users/venelin/Development/CEFTest/CEFTest/QCefView/src/details/QCefConfigPrivate.cpp:5:
In file included from /Users/venelin/Qt/6.6.0/macos/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/QDir:1:
In file included from /Users/venelin/Qt/6.6.0/macos/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qdir.h:9:
/Users/venelin/Qt/6.6.0/macos/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qfileinfo.h:134:22: error: 'path' is unavailable: introduced in macOS 10.15
    std::filesystem::path filesystemSymLinkTarget() const
                     ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.0.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/filesystem:909:24: note: 'path' has been explicitly marked unavailable here
class _LIBCPP_TYPE_VIS path {
                       ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
make[2]: *** [QCefView/src/CMakeFiles/QCefView.dir/details/QCefConfigPrivate.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [QCefView/src/CMakeFiles/QCefView.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
☁  build
```

Any idea why do I get this error and how can I fix it ?

Already tried with: `cmake -DCMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.15  ..` but it seems to change nothing.

Comment: Mac defaults to compiling to C++98 which reads like it would be way more advanced than C++17, minimum needed to get filesystem support, but the number is the year the Standard revision was ratified. Sort of like how you're using Windows 11 when your parents got to use Windows 2000.

Comment: @user4581301 how can I change that so that it compiles at the end ?

Comment: [Give this a read](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/CXX_STANDARD.html) and add the command to your project's CMakeLists.txt file. If it's already there or you can't figure out exactly where to put the command, add the CMakeLists.txt file to the question and we'll help you fix the file up.

Comment: @user4581301 I've added CMakeLists.txt thank you!

Comment: Well... It's there all right, and it looks OK to me. You'll need someone with a higher belt in Mac-Fu than I've got

Comment: Try to move `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD...` above `project(...` and delete the fileCMakeCache.txt.

Comment: The modern way of setting C++ version is `target_compile_features(CEFTest PRIVATE cxx_std_17)`

Comment: @273K still same issue.

Comment: Show the actual compiler invocation command. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670121/using-cmake-with-gnu-make-how-can-i-see-the-exact-commands

Comment: @273K here it is: https://pastebin.com/ynMKgtJn

Comment: No, not to there. Get one full command and post it in the question.

Answer (score 1):

1. std::filesystem::path is only supported from macOS 10.15+
2. for Qt version < 6.5, Qt doesn't use std::filesystem::path so that it can support macOS version below 10.15
3. starting from 6.5 Qt only supports for macOS 11+, and Qt uses std::filesystem::path

But QCefView still need to support macOS 10.13+, if you want to compile QCefView with Qt 6.5+, that means the minimum deployment target should be macOS 11.0+.

Please refer to: https://github.com/CefView/QCefView/issues/341