building OpenCV on Ubuntu (Undefined reference to `g_memdup2’)
How would you safely go about what appears to be an outdated (or too new) version of libpangosft on Ubuntu, when building OpenCV from source on Ubuntu 22.04?
[ 18%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/opencv_test_core
/usr/bin/ld: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0: undefined reference to `g_memdup2'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I have followed from the official OpenCV build guide both with and without opencv_contrib, while also using -DBUILD_TIFF=ON due to an earlier incompatibility to system installed libraries.
This is with Ubuntu 22.04.
$ apt list libglib2.0-*
libglib2.0-dev-bin/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 2.72.4-0ubuntu2.3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libglib2.0-dev-bin/jammy-updates,jammy-security 2.72.4-0ubuntu2.3 i386
libglib2.0-dev/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 2.72.4-0ubuntu2.3 amd64 [installed]
libglib2.0-dev/jammy-updates,jammy-security 2.72.4-0ubuntu2.3 i386
libglib2.0-doc/jammy-updates,jammy-updates,jammy-security,jammy-security 2.72.4-0ubuntu2.3 all
libglib2.0-tests/jammy-updates,jammy-security 2.72.4-0ubuntu2.3 amd64
libglib2.0-tests/jammy-updates,jammy-security 2.72.4-0ubuntu2.3 i386

libglib2.0-dev is already the newest version (2.72.4-0ubuntu2.3).
$ ldd /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc91dd9000)
    libpango-1.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpango-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f99f8f43000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f99f8e09000)
    libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f99f8da9000)
    libgio-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f99f8bcf000)
    libharfbuzz.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so.0 (0x00007f99f8b00000)
    libfontconfig.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1 (0x00007f99f8ab4000)
    libfreetype.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007f99f89ec000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f99f87c3000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f99f86dc000)
    libfribidi.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfribidi.so.0 (0x00007f99f86c0000)
    libthai.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthai.so.0 (0x00007f99f86b5000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f99f863d000)
    libffi.so.8 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.8 (0x00007f99f8630000)
    libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f99f8629000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f99f860d000)
    libmount.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmount.so.1 (0x00007f99f85c9000)
    libselinux.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007f99f859d000)
    libgraphite2.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgraphite2.so.3 (0x00007f99f8574000)
    libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f99f8543000)
    libuuid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007f99f853a000)
    libpng16.so.16 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16 (0x00007f99f84ff000)
    libbrotlidec.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbrotlidec.so.1 (0x00007f99f84f1000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f99f8fea000)
    libdatrie.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdatrie.so.1 (0x00007f99f84e6000)
    libblkid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libblkid.so.1 (0x00007f99f84af000)
    libpcre2-8.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre2-8.so.0 (0x00007f99f8418000)
    libbrotlicommon.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbrotlicommon.so.1 (0x00007f99f83f5000)

$ cmake --build . --verbose
[ 16%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/opencv_test_core
cd opencv/build/modules/core && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/opencv_test_core.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++    -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Wreturn-type -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Waddress -Wsequence-point -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Wsuggest-override -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG   -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,--no-undefined CMakeFiles/opencv_test_core.dir/test/ocl/test_arithm.cpp.o CMakeFiles/opencv_test_core.dir/test/ocl/test_channels.cpp.o CMakeFiles/opencv_test_core.dir/test/ocl/test_dft.cpp.o CMakeFiles/opencv_test_core.dir/test/ocl/test_gemm.cpp.o CMakeFiles/opencv_test_core.dir/test/ocl/test_image2d.cpp.o CMakeFiles/opencv_test_core.dir/test/ocl/test_matrix_expr.cpp.o CMakeFiles/opencv_test_core.dir/test/ocl/test_matrix_operation.cpp.o CMakeFiles/opencv_test_core.dir/test/ocl/test_opencl.cpp.o CMakeFiles/opencv_test_core.dir/test/test_arithm.cpp.o CMakeFiles/opencv_test_core.dir/test/test_async.cpp.o CMakeFiles/opencv_test_core.dir/test/test_concatenation.cpp.o CMakeFiles/opencv_test_core.dir/test/test_conjugate_gradient.cpp.o CMakeFiles/opencv_test_core.dir/test/test_countnonzero.cpp.o CMakeFiles/opencv_test_core.dir/test/test_cuda.cpp.o CMakeFiles/opencv_test_core.dir/test/test_downhill_simplex.cpp.o CMakeFiles/opencv_test_core.dir/test/test_ds.cpp.o CMakeFiles/opencv_test_core.dir/test/test_dxt.cpp.o CMakeFiles/opencv_test_core.dir/test/test_eigen.cpp.o CMakeFiles/opencv_test_core.dir/test/test_hal_core.cpp.o CMakeFiles/opencv_test_core.dir/test/test_hasnonzero.cpp.o CMakeFiles/opencv_test_core.dir/test/test_intrin.cpp.o CMakeFiles/opencv_test_core.dir/test/test_intrin_emulator.cpp.o CMakeFiles/opencv_test_core.dir/test/test_io.cpp.o CMakeFiles/opencv_test_core.dir/test/test_logtagconfigparser.cpp.o CMakeFiles/opencv_test_core.dir/test/test_logtagmanager.cpp.o CMakeFiles/opencv_test_core.dir/test/test_lpsolver.cpp.o CMakeFiles/opencv_test_core.dir/test/test_main.cpp.o CMakeFiles/opencv_test_core.dir/test/test_mat.cpp.o CMakeFiles/opencv_test_core.dir/test/test_math.cpp.o CMakeFiles/opencv_test_core.dir/test/test_misc.cpp.o CMakeFiles/opencv_test_core.dir/test/test_opencl.cpp.o CMakeFiles/opencv_test_core.dir/test/test_operations.cpp.o CMakeFiles/opencv_test_core.dir/test/test_ptr.cpp.o CMakeFiles/opencv_test_core.dir/test/test_quaternion.cpp.o CMakeFiles/opencv_test_core.dir/test/test_rand.cpp.o CMakeFiles/opencv_test_core.dir/test/test_rotatedrect.cpp.o CMakeFiles/opencv_test_core.dir/test/test_umat.cpp.o CMakeFiles/opencv_test_core.dir/test/test_utils.cpp.o CMakeFiles/opencv_test_core.dir/test/test_intrin128.sse2.cpp.o CMakeFiles/opencv_test_core.dir/test/test_intrin128.sse3.cpp.o CMakeFiles/opencv_test_core.dir/test/test_intrin128.ssse3.cpp.o CMakeFiles/opencv_test_core.dir/test/test_intrin128.sse4_1.cpp.o CMakeFiles/opencv_test_core.dir/test/test_intrin128.sse4_2.cpp.o CMakeFiles/opencv_test_core.dir/test/test_intrin128.fp16.cpp.o CMakeFiles/opencv_test_core.dir/test/test_intrin128.avx.cpp.o CMakeFiles/opencv_test_core.dir/test/test_intrin128.avx2.cpp.o CMakeFiles/opencv_test_core.dir/test/test_intrin256.avx2.cpp.o CMakeFiles/opencv_test_core.dir/test/test_intrin128.avx512_skx.cpp.o CMakeFiles/opencv_test_core.dir/test/test_intrin256.avx512_skx.cpp.o CMakeFiles/opencv_test_core.dir/test/test_intrin512.avx512_skx.cpp.o -o ../../bin/opencv_test_core  -Wl,-rpath,opencv/build/lib:anaconda3/lib ../../lib/libopencv_ts.a ../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.4.10.0 -ldl -lm -lpthread -lrt ../../3rdparty/lib/libippiw.a ../../3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx/icv/lib/intel64/libippicv.a ../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.10.0 ../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.4.10.0 ../../lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.4.10.0 ../../lib/libopencv_core.so.4.10.0 -lm -lpthread -lrt -Wl,-rpath-link,anaconda3/lib


Have you installed libglib2.0-dev?

Yes, version 2.72.4-0ubuntu2.3 of it is installed @3CxEZiVlQ

Can you try ldd /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 and check which library is "not found"?

Also, try cmake --build . --verbose so you can see the exact build command that failed. (found at https://stackoverflow.com/a/63690389)

I  have the same versions of the mentioned libraries and it compiled clean for me. What exact version of opencv are you building?

Include the output from apt list libglib2.0-* in your question please.

So through this discussion and the kind contributions explaining what to look at when starting out on such matters, I have noticed that anaconda, which I've not been using for a long while, seems to pop up a lot, and uninstalling anaconda the build is on its safe way to successful completion now without any other changes being required. Thanks @TedLyngmo for letting me know it's working in your equivalent setup which paved the way for connecting the dots on it, and for all of the kind tips from everyone!

Just for the record, in my specific case after uninstalling Anaconda it builds as is.

It is a GLib error, as this function should be presented from any version of GLib since 2.68. Maybe, it is necessary to update the libpango-dev installation. Also, I suppose, there could be a linking issue when the test executable opencv_test_core is not declared explicitly linked to GTK library set due to some unhandled case in the build scenario. This could be fixed using something like this trick.

As a case in point for similar cases, how do we trace back from the original error message, that it is a GLib error?

g_memdup2 is a Glib function
