Linking to stdc++fs (std::experimental::filesystem) doesn't work
This is my CMakeLists.txt file for a project I am trying to run, everything seems fine up until the filesystem library, I tried a couple of things and what worked for me is the std::experimental::filesystem
g++ and gcc version g++ (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0, gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
project(emsgc1)

find_package(catkin_simple REQUIRED)
catkin_simple(ALL_DEPS_REQUIRED)

SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++17 -O3")

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(gsl REQUIRED gsl)

include_directories("/usr/include/eigen3")
###########
## Build ##
###########

## Specify additional locations of header files
## Your package locations should be listed before other locations
include_directories(include
    third-party/gco
    third-party/delaunator/include
    ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})

set(HEADERS
    include/emsgc/core/event_motion_segmentation.h
    include/emsgc/core/image_warped_events.h
    include/emsgc/core/numerical_deriv.h
    include/emsgc/core/contrastFunctor.h
    include/emsgc/container/EventQueueMat.h
    include/emsgc/container/EventMRF.h
    include/emsgc/container/PerspectiveCamera.h
    include/emsgc/tools/utils.h
    include/emsgc/tools/TicToc.h
    third-party/gco/energy.h
    third-party/gco/block.h
    third-party/gco/GCoptimization.h
    third-party/gco/graph.h
    third-party/gco/LinkedBlockList.h
    third-party/delaunator/include/delaunator.hpp)

set(HEADERS
    include/emsgc/core/event_motion_segmentation.h
    include/emsgc/core/image_warped_events.h
    include/emsgc/core/numerical_deriv.h
    include/emsgc/core/contrastFunctor.h
    include/emsgc/container/EventQueueMat.h
    include/emsgc/container/EventMRF.h
    include/emsgc/container/PerspectiveCamera.h
    include/emsgc/tools/utils.h
    include/emsgc/tools/TicToc.h
    third-party/gco/energy.h
    third-party/gco/block.h
    third-party/gco/GCoptimization.h
    third-party/gco/graph.h
    third-party/gco/LinkedBlockList.h
    third-party/delaunator/include/delaunator.hpp)

set(SOURCES
    src/container/PerspectiveCamera.cpp
    src/core/event_motion_segmentation.cpp
    src/core/image_warped_events.cpp
    src/core/optim_contrast_gsl.cpp
    src/core/numerical_deriv.cpp
    src/core/optimizeLabels.cpp
    src/core/optimizeModels.cpp
    third-party/gco/GCoptimization.cpp
    third-party/gco/graph.cpp
    third-party/gco/LinkedBlockList.cpp
    third-party/gco/maxflow.cpp)
cs_add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}_LIB ${HEADERS} ${SOURCES})

## Node
link_libraries(stdc++fs)
cs_add_executable(emsgc_main emsgc_main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(emsgc_main ${PROJECT_NAME}_LIB ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES} yaml-cpp ${gsl_LIBRARIES} "stdc++fs")

The error is that for some reason it is not linking the stdc++fs when it is there ate the end, if I try to post the verbose output, it flags as the question is mostly code haha
Errors     << emsgc:make /home/suhail/catkin_ws/logs/emsgc/build.make.002.log                                                                                                                              
CMakeFiles/emsgc_main.dir/emsgc_main.cpp.o: In function `std::experimental::filesystem::v1::__cxx11::path::path<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::experimental::filesystem::v1::__cxx11::path>(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
emsgc_main.cpp:(.text._ZNSt12experimental10filesystem2v17__cxx114pathC2INSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEES3_EERKT_[_ZNSt12experimental10filesystem2v17__cxx114pathC5INSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEES3_EERKT_]+0x6c): undefined reference to `std::experimental::filesystem::v1::__cxx11::path::_M_split_cmpts()'
CMakeFiles/emsgc_main.dir/emsgc_main.cpp.o: In function `main':
emsgc_main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x8e7): undefined reference to `std::experimental::filesystem::v1::create_directories(std::experimental::filesystem::v1::__cxx11::path const&)'
emsgc_main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x929): undefined reference to `std::experimental::filesystem::v1::create_directories(std::experimental::filesystem::v1::__cxx11::path const&)'
emsgc_main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x969): undefined reference to `std::experimental::filesystem::v1::create_directories(std::experimental::filesystem::v1::__cxx11::path const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [/home/suhail/catkin_ws/devel/lib/emsgc/emsgc_main] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/emsgc_main.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2


When I create a test.cpp file to try it out, it works
#include <experimental/filesystem>
namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;

int main() {
    fs::path p = "/tmp";
    return 0;
}

using
g++ -std=c++17 test.cpp -lstdc++fs


You could try to have a minimal CMakeLists.txt file that works (like this one) and then add the other parts one after the other one.

Are you sure it's not just because this ancient version of GCC does not have the necessary functions?

You should check the commands being used to make sure you're getting what you expect https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670121/using-cmake-with-gnu-make-how-can-i-see-the-exact-commands

If you're using C++17, filesystem should not be experimental but fully part of the standard.  See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem. Are you sure you are compiling with C++17 standard enabled?

@PepijnKramer filesystem was added in libstdc++ 8, they're using 7 https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/17#C.2B.2B17_library_features
